# PDF download wont work in Laravel Project

Tags: php, laravel, pdf

Im new to laravel and I cant seem to download the pdf of my blade php file. Please help me out! Thank you!

**This is what I get If i click my "Export to PDF" button in my productlist.blade.php:**

*ErrorException
Undefined variable: products (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\productcrud\resources\views\productlist.blade.php)*

**This is my product controller file:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Product;
use Barryvdh\DomPDF\Facade as PDF;

class ProductController extends Controller
{
...

public function showProductList(){
    $products = Product::all();
    return view('productlist', compact('products'));
  }

  public function createPDF() {
  $data = Product::all();

  view()->share('productlist',$data);
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('productlist', $data);

  return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
  }
 }
```

**This is the body of my productlist.blade.php:**

```
<body>
<div class="container mt-4">
<div class="card bg-light border-warning">
<div class="card-header">
    <h2 class="text-center display-4 mb-3">Product List</h2>

    <div class="float-right">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="{{ URL::to('/productlist/pdf') }}">Export to PDF</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary m-2 btn-lg" href="{{ route('products.index') }}"> Back</a>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card-body">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped text-center">
        <thead>
            <tr class="thead-dark text-center">
        <th scope="col">No.</th>

        <th scope="col">Name</th>

        <th scope="col">Image</th>

        <th scope="col">Barcode</th>

        <th scope="col">Price</th>

        <th scope="col">Quantity</th>

        <th scope="col">Status</th>

        <th scope="col">Created At</th>

        <th scope="col">Updated At</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach($products as $product)
            <tr>
            
        <td>{{ $product->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->name }}</td>
        <td><img src ="{{ asset('storage/images/products/'.$product->image) }}" alt ="" width ="80px"></td>
        <td>{{ $product->barcode }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->price }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->status }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $product->updated_at }}</td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" type="text/js"></script>
</body>
```

**This is my web.php:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\ProductController;
use App\Http\Controllers\PDFController;

Route::get('/', function () {
return view('welcome');
});

Route::resource('products', ProductController::class);
Route::get('/productlist', 'App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@showProductList');
Route::get('/productlist/pdf','App\Http\Controllers\ProductController@createPDF');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code to use this:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('productlist', ['products' => $data]);
```

When passing data to a view, as is what's happening above, you should pass an associative array. Then, for each key in that array, laravel will automatically create a variable in the scope of the view file's code with that name and value.

For example, in the above, we send: `['products' => $data]` and laravel will create a `$products` variable whose value will be `$data` and that variable can be used by the view.

[See the related docs here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/views#passing-data-to-views)

Comment: I updated it to this now: public function createPDF() {
      $data = Product::all();
      view()->share('productlist',$data);
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('productlist', ['products' => $data]);
      return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
      }

but when I click the Export to PDF button, it starts to load this happened: Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: @InspiritC its hard to know for sure but it sounds like it's taking longer than your max execution time to create the PDF from your data. I see you're doing `$data = Product::all();`, Does the products table contain a large number of rows or columns with a large amount of data?  If so, you could increase the max execution time via `ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); //300 seconds = 5 minutes` or by setting it in your php.ini file. If the data isnt large, you might have an infinite loop somewhere causing the issue.

Comment: @InspiritC note, if a large data set is indeed the issue, you may also get an error indicating that you need to increase your memory_limit.

Comment: Where can i put that code? in the php.ini file in xampp folder? and i think yess it has a large data

Comment: If you use `ini_set('max_execution_time', '300'); ` , you can put that at the top of your `createPDF` function. If you set it in your php.ine, either find and edit or add this line to the `php.ine` file used by your server `max_execution_time = 300`, you can find that file like this http://prntscr.com/uol6v7

Answer (score 0):

You can change one of your codes to below:

```
$pdf = PDF::loadView('productlist', ['products' => $data]);
```

or

```
view()->share('products', $data);
```

Use both of them is useless, So you should use one of them. I recommend the first one, because `view()->share()` method usually use for global variable in view. But you can do it in every controller too.

Comment: public function createPDF() {
      $data = Product::all();
      $pdf = PDF::loadView('productlist', ['products' => $data]);
      return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
      }

It loads but it results to this error(?) : Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Maximum execution time of 60 seconds exceeded

Comment: and i also tried this: 
      public function createPDF() {
      $data = Product::all();
      view()->share('products', $data);
      return $pdf->download('pdf_file.pdf');
      } 
but the error is: ErrorException
Undefined variable: pdf